# How to simultaneously apply color/shape/size in a scatter plot using plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to create (in `plotly`) a scatterplot which distinguishes the points of the same series by two (or three) aesthetics -- color, shape, size. Ultimately the objective is to be able to toggle groups of points on/off via the legend, using any of the three aesthetics. This works well for one aesthetic.

**[Added 2016-06-20]** To expand on the desired interactive behavior: The idea is, once the figure is shown, to be able to toggle groups of points by clicking on any of the legends. For example (in the sample data below), if I were to click on `y` in the legend, it would hide/show points #4, 5 and 10 from all series. If there's a click on `A`, then toggle points #1, 2 and 8.
As a real-life use case -- think bond prices, with maturity on the horizontal axis and price on the vertical. Bonds are characterized by country of origin, credit rating and issue size. So if I click on, say, credit rating "A", I'd like all A-rated issues, regardless of size and country of origin, to be hidden. Currently they are only hidden from the rating-related trace. The points in the traces which reflect the other attributes (size & country) remain shown.
Given the detailed answer below, I am inclined to post this as a feature request on `plotly`'s site.

*I have framed the question for `plotly`, but if this behavior can be achieved in another package/library from R with relatively low pain levels (meaning no custom JavaScript or the like), I will accept that as an answer too.*
**[end edit]**

The static part is easily done in `ggplot2` but I cannot recreate it in `plotly` (for the interactivity), even using `ggplotly()`. Not sure if it is possible at all, but thought I'd ask. Sample data & code below.

(Possibly related to [Using 2+ legends from R to plotly / plot.ly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102941/using-2-legends-from-r-to-plotly-plot-ly))

Generate some dummy data:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)


DT <- data.table(
    x = c(1:10), y = 1:10/2,
    gr1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "B", "A", "E", "E"),
    gr2 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z", "x", "x", "y"),
    gr3 = c(1,2,2,1,3,4,1,2,2,1)
)
```

The `ggplot()` version looks like this, and is what I'd like to get in plotly:

```
p <- ggplot(data = DT) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = gr1, shape = gr2, size = gr3))
p
```

There are three groups of criteria in the legend, and the points have varying color, shape and size.
[image: ggplot version]

Calling `ggplotly(p)` generates a bunch of warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: In if (s == Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and produces this figure:

[image: ggplotly version]

Trying to use `plot_ly()`, I get the following:

```
plot_ly(data = DT, x = x, y = y, color = gr1, symbol = gr2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", marker = list(size = 10 * gr3)) # size is multiplied by 10, in plotly it is in pixels
```

[image: plot_ly version]

The problem is most obvious in the middle of the figure -- instead of a colored cross, there are several shapes in different colors overlaid onto one another. Since this is a single point, I am expecting a single colored shape, as in `ggplot`. In plotly, do the 'color', 'symbol' and 'size' arguments create a new trace?

I am still quite new to `plotly`, so I may be missing something obvious.

The above is done using `R 3.2.2` under Windows, with `plotly_2.0.16` and `ggplot2_2.0.0`.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, plotly does not give this behaviour automatically. But, it can be done simply enough by specifying the colour, shape, and size of each point individually -- using the `colors =`, `size =`, and `symbols =` arguments.  This allows control over how the points are plotted, but does not get the legend you want. So we use `showlegend = FALSE` in the main plot and construct the legend by adding three more (invisible) traces that are only there to generate the legend items.

Note that there is one more trick we need to apply here.  To get a legend showing colours or sizes, you can use the argument `visible = "legendonly"` which creates a legend entry without over-plotting extra points on the graph. BUT this does not work with shapes. Combining `visible = "legendonly"` with `symbols =` seems to have a bug that puts the wrong items in the legend.  So, to create the legend entries for shapes, you can plot them at a location far out in the stratosphere where they will never be visible (here I used x=y=1e6) and set the x and y axis limits to keep these out of view.

```
DT <- data.table(
  x = c(1:10), y = 1:10/2,
  gr1 = as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "B", "A", "E", "E")),
  gr2 = as.factor(c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z", "x", "x", "y")),
  gr3 = c(1,2,2,1,3,4,1,2,2,1)
)
shapes <- c("circle", "square", "diamond","cross", "x","square-open","circle-open","diamond-open")
DT$shapes <- shapes[DT$gr1]
DT$col <- rainbow(3)[DT$gr2]
DT$size <- DT$gr3*10

plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = DT, x = x, y = y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
            color=gr2, colors=col,
            marker = list(size = size, symbol=shapes), showlegend=F) %>%
  add_trace(data = DT, x = x, y = y, type = "scatter",mode = "markers", 
            color= factor(gr2), colors=col, 
            visible="legendonly", showlegend=T, legendgroup="color",
            marker = list(size = 14)) %>%
  add_trace(data = DT, x = x, y = y, type = "scatter",mode = "markers", 
            color=factor(gr3), colors="#000000", 
            marker = list(size = size),
            visible="legendonly", showlegend=T, legendgroup="size") %>%
  add_trace(data = DT, x = 1e6, y = 1e6, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
            color=factor(gr1), colors="#000000", 
            marker = list(size=14, symbol=shapes),
            showlegend=T, legendgroup="shape") %>%
  layout(legend=list(traceorder="grouped+reversed", tracegroupgap =30),
         xaxis=list(range=c(0,12)),
         yaxis=list(range=c(0,6)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, the "far out in the stratosphere" is a great touch :) It does appear to solve the visual part to a large extent (clicking on the legend destroys the effect, as it plots another shape onto the previous ones). The basic question, however, was the interactivity (in the first sentence) -- which does not seem to work. The idea is, if I click on either `C`, `y` or `1` in the legends to have point #4 (x = 4, y = 2.0) disappear. It would have to hide the respective point from all three series, which I am not sure is possible in stock `plotly`.

Comment: If you don't want clicking the legend to overplot the points (this effectively toggles the visibility state), then just use the stratosphere method for each of the legend items. If you want more complex behaviour than this, then good luck... Doubt you can do it in plotly.

Comment: Yes, I figured I want too much :) I'm open to suggestions for other packages/libraries than can do this, if they exist. Thank you again -- even though I can't accept the answer to this immediate question, I did learn a useful trick.

Comment: The question was "How to simultaneously apply color/shape/size in a scatter plot using plotly?" You don't think I answered that?????

Comment: Running the risk of sounding ungrateful (which is not the case!), this is the *title* of the question, not the question itself. The second sentence clarifies it's all about an interactive version, not a static plot. I also think the others who have marked the question expect interactivity. If I were to mark the question as answered, it would be misleading.