# How to group the labels in plotly.R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a shape aesthetic and a color aesthetic. Plotly labels each trace separately. Is there a way to group the labels by color and shape, like in ggplot?

Mini example:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = wt ,shape = as.factor(am), col=as.factor(cyl)))+geom_point()

p

ggplotly(p)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simultaneously apply color/shape/size in a scatter plot using plotly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582584/how-to-simultaneously-apply-color-shape-size-in-a-scatter-plot-using-plotly)